# Change loaded Widget outside of Main file (setState not available)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a MainScreen() file where I defined two Widgets, side by side:

- Left menu (ListTiles).
- Main View (rest of screen, to the right).

My issue is that I need to tap the ListTiles on the left and dynamically change the Widget loaded on the Main View.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main view must be stateful for this to work, as you need to trigger a rerender once you tap one of the tiles. You want to pass a callback function from your main screen to your menu of list tiles.

Your best bet is to setup an enum and have each listtile provide the callback with its own enum value.

Once you have the callback in your list of tiles, you can easily pass it onward to the individual tiles. Then, execute the callback function `onTap` and provide it with the correct enum value.

On your main screen, you just show the correct widget by looking at the current enum value.

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  MyEnum _currentTile = MyEnum.Home;
  
  void _callbackFunction(MyEnum tileOption) {
     setState(() {
       _currentTile = tileOption;
     });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyCustomListTile((MyEnum tile) => _callbackFunction(tile) );
  }
}
```